# Freed pointer reallocaing itself?

Tags: c, struct, structure, dynamic-allocation

When I dynamically allocate a structure, and then try to free it, it seems to reallocate it.

```
typedef struct OBJ_T
{
   int param1, param2;
} OBJ;

OJB* Construct(int par1, int par2)
{
   OBJ* x = malloc(sizeof(OBJ));
   x->param1 = par1;
   x->param2 = par2;
   return x;
}

void freeup(OBJ *x)
{
   printf("x pointer -> %d ", x);
   free(x);
   x=NULL;
   printf("\nx pointer -> %d\n", x);
}

int main()
{
   OBJ foo = *Construct(10, 20);
   freeup(&foo);
   freeup(&foo);
   return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
x pointer -> 2752216
x pointer -> 0
x pointer -> 2752216
x pointer -> 0
```

So after freeing and nulling out the pointer, if I check it again, it goes back to what it was. Is that a problem? Or is it free and I don't have to worry about it anymore?

Comment: The pointer abuse group will be wanting a word with you. On a serious note, you are losing the original pointer already in the line `OBJ foo = *Construct(10,20)`.

Comment: Seems you have a Java or Delphi background? So there is something to learn about pointers.

Comment: It is not possible to call `free()` on memory allocated on the stack: `freeup(&foo);`

Comment: @alk but seems *possible*, It's clear: you should never do this. Can you describe what happens here? UB?

Comment: @Wolf: "It **seems** possible." Is a **very** weak argument in C.

Comment: Sure, calling `free()` on anything not a null-pointer or allocated by `malloc/calloc/realloc` invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour, after which  anything can happen. @Wolf

Comment: Note: `OBJ* x` is somewhat missleading when read. move the space before the `*`: `OBJ *x`. See this construct `int* ip, i;` remember: `i` will **not** be a pointer as the visual binding of the `*` to `int` implies. Instead the `*` only belongs to `ip`.

Comment: I see (what I expected). But it also had been possible, that free had a built-in is-stack test (I'm happy to have stopped using `free` when changing from C to C++). Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this line is allocates `foo` on the stack and then copies dynamically allocated struct to the place:

```
OBJ foo = *Construct(10, 20);
```

Of cause, you shouldn't free it. Correct case is:

```
OBJ* foo = Construct(10, 20);
. . .
freeup(foo);
```

Second, if you want to clear pointer in `freeup`, then change the type of parameter to pointer-to-pointer:

```
void freeup(OBJ** x)
{
   free(*x);
   *x=NULL;
}
```

...In this case you should change the `freeup` call into `freeup(&foo);`.

Finally, it may seem that `foo` is reallocated in you code, but it just can't be freed or allocated, it's a stack variable. So pointer to `foo` is always the same inside the function.

Comment: You are double-freeing the allocated memory, which is a problem. You are also passing the value of the pointer twice (you have set a pass-by-value copy of &foo to 0, this does not change &foo).

Comment: Right. ...but it doesn't answer the original question. Maybe suggest a `OBJ **x` parameter as well. (or better not?)

Comment: @Wolf Is my comment clearer now? I completely forgot that pressing the return key doesn't give me a new line and instead submitted the comment. :/

Comment: ... and call `freeup(OBJ **)` like this `freeup(&foo);`.

Comment: @alk I added a line to complete this *option*

Answer (score 2):

You are losing your pointer in the line

```
OBJ foo = *Construct(10, 20);
```

You take the struct `OBJ` that the pointer returned by `Construct` points to, copy its values to `foo` and then throw away the pointer.
After that, because you have no pointer, you have no way to free the actual `struct OBJ` allocated by `Constructor`.

Your `freeup` calls are wrong then, because you try to free `foo`, rather than the original.

The correct way is to either keep working with the pointer, so

```
OBJ *foo = Construct(10, 20);
...
freeup(foo);
```

or not use pointers at all and just return an `OBJ` in `Construct`, rather than an `OBJ*`. That way, there is no need to worry about freeing anything.

Comment: I see now that I should've just not used pointers as I don't really _need_ to. I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 OBJ foo = *Construct(10, 20);
```

Due to this you looses your pointer which points to block allocated by `malloc` . So `free`ing memory not allocated by `malloc` or similar cause error in program.

And this I really don't understand (taking in general - should not be done with pointer also )-

```
freeup(&foo);              // just one call is enough 
freeup(&foo);              // Why twice ?
```

And this -

```
  void freeup(OBJ *x)
{
    printf("x pointer -> %d ", x);
    free(x);
    x=NULL;
    printf("\nx pointer -> %d\n", x);          // should not be done in any case after assigning pointer to NULL
}
```

You can do this instead-

```
  void freeup(OBJ **x)
   {
        printf("x pointer -> %d ", *x);
        free(*x);
       *x = NULL;
  }
```

Call it in a same manner as you do `freeup(&foo);`

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code:

1. Losing reference to the original malloc'd pointer
2. Trying to free an object on the stack
3. Assigning 0 to the copy of the pointer (passed to freeup)

(1) The line `OBJ foo = *Construct(10, 20);` doen't assign the pointer to the allocated OBJ to foo, but copies the `OBJ`'s value to the stack, to a variable named foo, this causes you to lose the reference to the allocated object (and cause a memory leak).

A better way to do it is to return the pointer itself, it's clearer, doesn't cause you to lose the reference, and more efficient:

```
OBJ *foo = Construct(10, 20);
```

Now foo is a pointer to the object, not the object itself.

(2) derived from (1), now that we use foo as a pointer to the malloc'd object, we can use free on it.

(3) Assigning to a parameter from the callee does not change the value in the caller site. This is known as [pass-by-value](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html), as only a copy of the value of the argument is passed to the callee. So let's change `freeup`:

```
void freeup(OBJ **x)
{
   printf("x pointer -> %d ", *x);
   free(*x);
   *x=NULL;
   printf("\nx pointer -> %d\n", *x);
}
```

This way, the value of the pointer at the caller site will be changed.

---

Note that I omitted NULL checks etc. to make the code clearer, but they should definitely be there.